# Как выбрать самую длинную строку из массива?

Tags: php

Есть обычный массив, типа:

```
$array = ['раз', 'два два', 'три три три', 'тест'];
```

Как из него выбрать значение(строку) которая имеет наибольшее количество символов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = ['раз', 'два два', 'три три три', 'тест'];

$maxStringInArray = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    return mb_strlen($carry, 'utf-8') < mb_strlen($item, 'utf-8') ? $item : $carry;
}, '');

echo $maxStringInArray;
```

Прошу заметить, здесь не учтено то, что строк с одинаковым количеством символов может быть больше 1. Если это нужно - то нужно складывать результат в массив например.

```
$array = ['раз', '134 hty при', 'два два', 'три три три', 'тест'];

usort($array, function($prev, $next) {
    return mb_strlen($prev, 'utf-8') < mb_strlen($next, 'utf-8');
});

$arrayItemMaxLengtn = mb_strlen($array[0], 'utf-8');

$itemsWithMaxLength = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($arrayItemMaxLengtn) {
    return mb_strlen($item, 'utf-8') === $arrayItemMaxLengtn;
});

var_dump($itemsWithMaxLength);
```

Comment: не надо сортировать массив для поиска максимума, это куча ненужных операций

Comment: @teran а если значений с максимальным количество несколько, то как? два цикла придётся  делать в любом случае

Comment: цикла то два, но они оба линейные и независимые. в отличие от сортировки. там сложность будет больше. на меленьком массиве не существенно, конечно, но все же. Хотя в целом, два цикла не обязательны. достаточно и одного, но больше копирования данных будет, чем с двумя.

Comment: @teran понял. тоже про сортировку подумал об этом. То есть, получается, можно вместо сортировки взять тот же array_reduce и там узнать длину. (т.к. там алгоритм проще) и уже дальше фильтр?

Comment: да просто заводите массив куда складываете строки _текущей_ максимальной длины. Нашли новую макс.длину, очистили старые строки, и заново его пополняете. То есть если нашлась длина больше, то массив очистить и добавить, если равно максимуму, то просто добавить, если меньше, то проходим мимо.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = ['раз', 'два два', 'три три три', 'тест'];

$max_line = '';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (mb_strlen($max_line, 'utf-8') < mb_strlen($value, 'utf-8') {
        $max_line = $value;
    }
}
```

// $max_line содержит нужную нам строку

Comment: а если изменить слегка алгоритм, то будет универсальней(сугубо имхо) =)
`if (mb_strlen($array[$max_line], 'utf-8') < mb_strlen($value, 'utf-8') {
$max_line = $key;`
На выходе мы знаем то же что и раньше + индекс в массиве

Answer (score 1):

Простым перебором в цикле с одним условием:

```
$array = ['раз', 'два два', 'три три три', 'тест'];

$max = 0;
$str = '';

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ( ($len = mb_strlen($item)) > $max ) {
        $str = $item;
        $max = $len;
    }
}

echo $str; // три три три
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = ['раз', 'два два', 'три три три', 'тест'];

$len = array_map('mb_strlen', $array);
echo $array[array_search(max($len), $len)];
```

https://3v4l.org/FMaTk

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = ['раз', 'два два', 'три три три', 'тест'];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    # code...

    $mb_str_len1[] = mb_strlen($value, 'utf-8');

}
print_r(max($mb_str_len1));
```

Comment: получается создается новый массив в котором записано макс кол-во символов? но как получить это значение из первого массива?...